# Start spring-boot project without datasource configuration on application.properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring-boot project where the database configuration should be saved in the first time the user execute the application, after ask for the connection data (server url, username and password). the `application.properties` file embbed in the WAR file of the application should be something like that:

```
security.basic.enabled=false

# THYMELEAF (ThymeleafAutoConfiguration)
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# Multipart Configuration
spring.servlet.multipart.maxFileSize = 150MB
spring.servlet.multipart.maxRequestSize = 150MB
spring.servlet.multipart.fileSizeThreshold = 5MB

# Setting max size of post requests to 6MB (default: 2MB)
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=157286400
```

After the first run, a second `application.properties` should be created with the database configuration. But right now, when I try run the project with the configuration above, it do not start, showing the following error message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

without give the application the change to generate the second configuration file, with the database properties.

How I could force the application to run this first time, even without the database stuff?

**update**

Ok, then I get rid of this error message by keeping this 2 dependencies on my `pom.xml`:

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       <version>LATEST</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

and now the applications runs without error, and I am able to open the installation page to create the database on the postgresql server and import the initial data (user data included).

But I notice that this initial data is not being stored on the postgresql server (despite the datababse and all the tables are being created normally). I suspect they are being created on the hyperSql database on memory, what do not help me at all.

My guess is that's happen because I autowire some Dao classes for this entities on my InstallService class, and the code only create the data on the postgresql where I directly make the connection with this specific server.

Considering the method responsible by populate de initial data on my database is something like that:

```
  public void criarUsuario(String user, String pass, String nome, String sobrenome, String email) {
    Usuario novo = new Usuario();
    novo.setUsername(user);
    novo.setPassword(pass);
    novo.setFirstName(nome);
    novo.setLastName(sobrenome);
    novo.setEmail(email);
    novo.setEnabled(true);
    novo.setLocked(false);
    novo.setCredenciais(new ArrayList<Credencial>());
    novo.getCredenciais().add( credencialDao.findBy("nome", "admin") );
    usuarioDao.insert(novo);
    ...
  }
```

What I could change here to persist this data on the postgresql database, instead of the hyperSql database?

**update 2**

Now I managed to run the application even with only the `postgresql` dependency om my `pom.xml`. I did that by adding a initial configuration on my first `application.properties` (locatd on `/src/main/resources`):

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/appdata
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=..
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

But when I try access the application on the browser, I got an error saying the database not exist (of course not, when I run the application the first time I have a specific flow to create database, tables and populate initial data).

is there any way to supress this "database not exist" error when I run the project?

Comment: You are not deploying WAR into a jee-app-server, but you are running the war from command line, aren't you? If so, you can give command line arguments `spring.profiles.active=production spring.config.location=path-to-application-production.properties\`, you may find more details from spring.io web site. Don't make it harder.

Comment: the solution should work either on command  line and deploying the war, because the final version, distributed to the final user, should have the same behavior (first run without establish a database connection, after that always establishing the connection)